# Find if time in row i in column A is before time in row i-1 in column B

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` of when patient appointment times are as well as how long these are. How do I find if the patient has left before the next one arrives: E.g. is `patient.time.in` before patient.time.out of the previous patient?

I would like to add a new column if patient.time.in[j] is before patient.time.out[j-1] then add a new column entry "Wait", if not then "No clash".

## For 12 patients

```
    patient.time.in=
        c("09:00:00","09:03:00",
          "09:30:00","09:38:00",
          "10:00:00","10:30:00",
          "11:00:00","11:05:00",
          "12:00:00","12:30:00",
          "14:30:00","15:30:00")

patient.date.in="2022/03/29"
```

## Their appointment length

```
appointment.length=c(runif(n=NROW(patient.time.in),min=10,max=90))

patient.infection=c("P","P","NA","P","C","NA","C","P","NA","NA","C","P")
```

## Set up the data.frame

```
  patient.roster=data.frame(
                          ID=seq(1:12),
                          patient.time.in=lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(patient.date.in,patient.time.in)),
                          patient.time.out=lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(patient.date.in,patient.time.in))+lubridate::minutes(round(appointment.length)),
                          patient.infection=patient.infection,
                          seen.yet=rep("No"),
                          binary.seen.yet=0)
```

## Check if the previous patient has left yet

Something like this:

```
patient.roster %>%
+   mutate(clash=case_when((patient.time.in[i]-patient.time.out[i-1])>0~"No Clash",
+                          TRUE~"Wait"))
```

Comment: `lubridate::hms` returns a time perioid (similar to duration) but no time point (e.g. a particular date)

Comment: @danlooo could you elaborate please?

Comment: In order to tell whether two patients are at the same place at the same time we need time points e.g. `2022-03-29 09:09:24 UTC` and not just  `09:00:00` which translate to 9 hours. We need Date and timezone as well.

Comment: @danlooo thanks for pointing that out. I've now fixed it in the question

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out:

```
patient.roster %>%
  mutate(value=patient.time.in-lag(patient.time.out))
```

Comment: Yep, was about to help you with it.
`patient.roster %>% 
  mutate(clash=case_when(patient.time.in < lag(patient.time.out)~"Wait",TRUE~"No Clash"))`